# sed - remove line break if line does not end on \"

Tags: macos, sed, line-breaks

I have a tsv.-file and there are some lines which do not end with an '"'. So now I would like to remove every line break which is not directly after an '"'.
How could I accomplish that with sed? Or any other bash shell program...

Kind regards,
Snafu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this awk one-liner a try:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(/"$/?"\n":"")}' file
```

test

```
kent$  cat f
"foo"
"bar"
"a long
text with
many many
lines"
"lalala"

kent$  awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(/"$/?"\n":"")}' f
"foo"
"bar"
"a longtext withmany manylines"
"lalala"
```

Answer (score 4):

This `sed` command should do it:

```
sed '/"$/!{N;s/\n//}' file
```

It says: on every line not matching `"$` do:

- read next line, append it to pattern space;
- remove linebreak between the two lines.

Example:

```
$  cat file.txt
"test"
"qwe
rty"
foo
$  sed '/"$/!{N;s/\n//}' file.txt
"test"
"qwerty"
foo
```

Comment: I get: sed: 1: "/"$/!{N;s/\n//}": bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Comment: I am on a mac. If this is relevant.

Comment: @SnafuBernd Are you using double quotes for the sed command? If so, please try using single quotes. Otherwise, it's one of those mac sed peculiarities

Comment: @SnafuBernd there's got to be a way with Mac sed as well. I'm sure someone else will know one.

Comment: Why the " before $?  Is this a shell escape?  I don't see it as needed in the documentation.

Comment: @jspencer it is a literal `"`

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it.  Seems like the range portion could just be '/$/!{...}', i.e. "on the last line, read a new line and substitute."  How does the " before the $ (last line) modify the range?  I couldn't find that in the texinfo docs...

Comment: @jspencer For the last line it would be just `$`. An address enclosed in `/slashes/` matches by regex. The regex is `"$`, i.e. a quote followed by the end of line. This is the reverse of the OP's requirement of "a line break which is not directly after an `"`".

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on @Lev's answer, the BSD (OSX) version of `sed` is less forgiving about the command syntax within the curly braces -- the semicolon command separator is required for both commands:

```
sed '/"$/!{N;s/\n//;}' file.txt
```

per the [documentation](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html) here -- an excerpt:

> Following an address or address range, sed accepts curly braces '{...}' so several commands may be applied to that line or to the lines matched by the address range. On the command line, semicolons ';' separate each instruction and must precede the closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/"$/!{N;s/\n//;ta}' file
```

This checks if the last character of the pattern space is a `"` and if not appends another line, removes a newline and repeats until the condition is met or the end-of-file is encountered.

An alternative is:

```
sed -r ':a;N;s/([^"])\n/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

The mechanism is left for the reader to ponder.